# My wired internet connection has stopped working

Tags: 14.04, internet

For a few days I haven't been able to connect to internet through a wired connection to my router on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I only have the problem when trying to use Ubuntu: the same desktop connects to the internet on Windows7; another desktop a laptop using Windows7 also connect wirelessly through the same router and a Windows 8 laptop is fine as well...

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu does the router assign your computer an IP address? If you open a terminal and type ifconfig you should see something like:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 01:02:03:04:05:06  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:5dff:fe30:2342/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1024:2048:3096:221:5dff:fe30:2342/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:1024:2048:3096:5015:f0ad:4336:5938/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:424242 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:424242 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f4600000-f4620000
```

If the "inet addr" shows a 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x address then you're at least getting an address from the router (meaning DHCP is working).

If you're not getting an IP address from the router, check your network connection settings: click the networking up/down arrows

[image: Ubuntu networking arrows]

click Edit

[image: Edit the network connection]

When the window appears click the Wired Connection 1 and Edit

[image: The Wired Connection Window]

Change to the IPv4 Settings tab and make sure it's set to Automatic (DHCP) (provided you're using DHCP). Also check the checkbox that says **Require IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete** is selected.

[image: Check the Require IPv4 addressing]

In your case it looks like you are getting an IPv6 address, but no IPv4 address. Some VOIP routers have issues with their IPv6 implementation. Windows tends to default to IPv4 which might explain why things work when you use Windows and not when you use Linux (which seems to be ONLY getting IPv6). Much of the world is moving to IPv6 but there are still some broken/buggy routers out there with bad implementations of IPv6. (Note: I'm using Xubuntu, your screens might be slightly different for Ubuntu).

Comment: Good first answer! ;-) Have a look at my edits and learn...  >:)

Comment: Thanks to Fabby and Charles for response. I really don't understand what is significant or not, so pls bear with me :-

Comment: :- when I enter ifconfig I get the following:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:d4:d1:66  
          inet6 addr:fe80::6e62:6dff:fed4:d166/64  Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:54813 (54.8 KB)  TX bytes:91969 (91.9 KB)

Comment: AND </h>l0        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr: 127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4448 (4.4 KB)  TX bytes:4448 (4.4 KB)

Comment: Sorry about lack of carriage returns - how do I add these into comments? Thx